# Could one field be added to different record types?

Tags: salesforce

I would like to know if one field could be added to multiple record type ?

Do I need a trigger for this or is it something related to salesforce record type system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Record types are used for different business processes to use different pagelayouts  and picklist values. There is nothing to worry about fields as they are independent from recordtypes.